# Is there any way to take an average from a whole set even when grouping (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have written a code in order to  output the following columns
ProductID, listprice, productcategoryID and

- Minimum ListPrice for the product category
- Maximum ListPrice for the product category
- Average ListPrice for all products

I have managed to do everything bar the last request, I imagine that I could simply use a CTE or a union and do the average formula separately and then attach it to the rest of the columns, but I wanted to know is there a way to run the average so it ignores the grouping within the query ?

Thank you for any input

```
select 
    productid, ListPrice, ProductCategoryID,
    first_value(listprice) over (partition by productcategoryID order by listprice ASC) as minforcat,
    first_value(listprice) over (partition by productcategoryID order by listprice DESC) as maxforcat,
    avg (listprice) as avg_price_overall
from
    Product
group by 
    productid, ProductCategoryID, listprice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want window functions like this:

```
select p.*,
       min(listprice) over (partition by productcategoryID) as minforcat,
       max(listprice) over (partition by productcategoryID) as maxforcat,
       avg(listprice) over () as avg_price_overall
from product p;
```

I'm not sure why you are aggregating.  It seems quite unlikely that there is more than one row per `productid` in a table called `product`.

Comment: The last function should be `avg`, not `min` I guess. Might be some copy-paste leftover?

Comment: Thank You that works perfectly, I  was clearly just over complicating it

Comment: Whilst it won't necessarily help in this particular case, you could look into the use of ROLLUP on the GROUP BY statement.